# Aws lambda returns /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am running an `AWS Lambda function` that uses one layer with `snowflake-connector-python`.

To create the layer I use:

```
docker run -v <your dev directory>:/lambda -it --rm ubuntu
apt-get update
apt-get install python3-pip 
apt-get install zip
cd lambda
mkdir -p temp/python
cd temp/python
pip3 install snowflake-connector-python -t .
cd ..
zip -r9 ../snowflake-connector-python.zip .
```

The lambda returns:

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 's3PutLambda': /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /opt/python/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "baa60d07-c9bb-4b32-a38f-3158eb50da09",
  "stackTrace": []
```

I tried also some other solutions, such as adding to the zip:

```
pip3 install cryptography==3.4.8
pip3 install bcrypt==3.2.2
```

The same error was raised.

Comment: Can you install a much newer version of cryptography like 38 for example and see if you still get the error?

Comment: @Sergiu not working, installed last version and same error.

Comment: It looks to be related to [this](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/6391)?

Comment: @Sergiu tested and not working. Still the same error.

Answer (score 4):

Finally solved, you need to downgrade `snowflake-connector-python` version and install it using platform `manylinux2010_x86_64`.

`pip` installs packages  from latest wheel unless you specify wheels version. The Python library packages I used were newer than the ones in runtime in Lambda backend containers.

If you specify manylinux2010 platform when installing the connector it fixes the issue.

The command I used is:

```
pip3 install --platform manylinux2010_x86_64 --implementation cp --python 3.8 --only-binary=:all: 
--upgrade --target . snowflake-connector-python==2.7.9
```

**Obs:**
I have not tested it with higher `snowflake-connector-python` versions, neither with higher python versions. I use `Python 3.8` runtime in `AWS Lambda`.

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered the exact same issue, and I managed to resolve it using a technique similar to what was suggested by @mrc back in 2017. To rectify the situation, I added the **snowflake-connector-python==2.7.9** library into a dummy virtual environment, which is then utilized to generate my Lambda layer zip folder. I accomplished this by running the following command::

```bash
pip3 install \
--platform manylinux2010_x86_64 \
--implementation cp \
--only-binary=:all: --upgrade \
--target venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ \
 snowflake-connector-python==2.7.9 boto3>=1.26.153 botocore>=1.29.153
```

It's essential to include both **boto3** and **botocore** libraries, and also, it's crucial to use python3.10, as elucidated in this comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76482246).

Answer (score 2):

1. Always try to build a lambda layer in a Linux environment.
2. Use the following pip syntax to build packages.

```bash
pip install --upgrade <pakage names> --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: -t .
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Installing packages this way worked for me.