# "cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_'" on AWS Lambda using a layer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

## What I want to achieve

To scrape an website using AWS Lambda and save the data on S3.

## The issues I'm having

When I execute Lambda, the following error message appears.

> {   "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot
> import name 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_'
> (/opt/python/urllib3/util/ssl_.py)",   "errorType":
> "Runtime.ImportModuleError",   "requestId":
> "fb66bea9-cbad-4bd3-bd4d-6125454e21be",   "stackTrace": [] }

## Code

The minimum Lambda code is as follows.

```
import requests
import boto3 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    upload_res = s3.put_object(Bucket='horserace-dx', Key='/raw/a.html', Body='testtext')
    
    return event
```

An layer was added to the Lambda. Files were save in `python` folder using the commands below , frozen in a zip file, then uploaded to AWS Lambda as a layer.

```
!pip install requests -t ./python --no-user
!pip install pandas -t ./python --no-user
!pip install beautifulsoup4 -t ./python --no-user
```

- The bucket `horserace-dx` exists
- The folder `raw` exists
- The role of the Lambda is properly set. It can read from and write to S3
- The runtime of the Lambda is Python 3.9. The python version of the local computer is 3.9.13.

## What I did so far

I google "cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_'" and found some suggestions. I made the layer with the following code and tried again in vain.

```
!pip install requests -t ./python --no-user
!pip install pandas -t ./python --no-user
!pip install beautifulsoup4 -t ./python --no-user
!pip install urllib3==1.26.15 -t ./python --no-user
```

So what should I do to achieve what I want to achieve? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you are installing that specific version of urllib?

Comment: @Paolo on this page (https://qiita.com/SatoshiGachiFujimoto/items/437b0ccaba817903fb72) there was a suggestion that the same error was solved using that version. I know the author was using docker while I'm not, but I tried that anyway.

Comment: Try `urllib3<2`

Comment: @Paolo I got the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Execute the following commands.

   pip install requests==2.25.0 -t ./python --no-user
   pip install beautifulsoup4 -t ./python --no-user
   pip install pytz -t ./python --no-user
2. On PyPI, download the following whl files from the pages of numpy and pandas

- numpy-1.24.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
- pandas-2.0.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

3. Unzip the files and move the contents to the `python` folder.
4. Zip the `python` folder and upload it to AWS Lambda Layer.
5. Set the layer to the Lambda.
6. Then the code runs without errors.

Answer (score 63):

> cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_'

You are encountering this issue because you’re using botocore which does not support urllib3 2.0 yet.

Since you’re deploying to AWS Lambda, you’ll need to explicitly pin to `urllib3<2` in your project to ensure urllib3 2.0 isn’t brought into your environment.
([Source](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v2-migration-guide.html#importerror-cannot-import-name-default-ciphers-from-urllib3-util-ssl))

```
urllib3<2
```

Follow [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html) for how to deploy Python Lambda functions with .zip file archives.

If you cannot get it to work via the .zip file, consider deploying via a container image instead by following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-create-from-base).

Comment: We noticed this change between *urllib3-2.0.3* version and *urllib3-2.1.0*

Answer (score 38):

In my case I just specified requests version (runtime python3.9) -

```
requests==2.28.2
```

and it worked.

Comment: 2.29.0 also worked for me
the full command is
pip install requests==2.29.0

Comment: pip install requests==2.28.2 -t ./. will install it only in your current folder

Comment: 2.31.0 didn't work. used 2.28.2 and it worked. using image with `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9-x86_64`. thanks for this comment @ashrafminhaj

Answer (score 11):

I solved it by setting `urllib3<2`. There is a breaking change with urllib3 2.0.

For example, if you have a requirement.txt file, then add a line `urllib3<2` to the file.

Refer to this for a better explanation: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6443#issuecomment-1535667256

Comment: this worked for me in bash: `pip install 'urllib3<2'`

Answer (score 6):

In my case,I encounter this error when using transformers library. I solved this problem by `pip install urllib3<2`

Comment: this worked for me in bash: `pip install 'urllib3<2'`

Answer (score 5):

The resolution that worked for me was to update the AWS Lambda runtime to `3.10` and if applicable any AWS Lambda layers to python `3.10` and then ensure you have packaged the latest release of requests. If you are using botocore or boto3 you will also need to ensure that you have included them in the code package or in an AWS Lambda Layer including versions `boto3>=1.26.153` and `botocore>=1.29.153`.

Comment: That's actually a little misleading, using previous stable version of libraries did solve the issue while using `python3.9` as runtime.

Comment: I am using `python3.8` and `urllib3==1.26.18` and installing `boto3==1.34.23`(previously 1.19.9) solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by using python 3.11 when setting up my lambda function in AWS, the lower versions tends to throw this error the more

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: upgrading lambda environment wasn't enough in my case--still had to rebuild package with correct `requests` version per @ashraf minhad

Answer (score 2):

This is because openai urllib3 issue

**Solution** : Open any folder and type this command **“pip install openai requests==2.29.0 urllib3==1.26.16 -t python”** this will install pip with these specific versions of requests and urllib3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this adding in your deployment.txt:

urllib3==1.16

Comment: This does not work, you will get error 'is_ipaddress' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_' (/var/task/urllib3/util/ssl_.py)",

1.26.16 works fine

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue, with this and other libraries. The root cause of the problem is library compatibility, so to solve it without specifying the library versions, we can use the lambda's runtime Docker image:

```
mkdir layer
cp requirements.txt layer/requirements.txt
docker run -ti -v $(pwd)/layer:/app -w /app --entrypoint /bin/bash public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11 -c "pip3 install --target ./python -r requirements.txt"
```

We get at layer/python, all the libraries that we need for the layer. Then we just zip it and create the layer in AWS.

Here I'm using Python 3.11 for the lambda, but any other version should work

**Note**: on windows powershell, change `$(pwd)` to `${pwd}`.

Answer (score 1):

In the requirements.txt add the line urllib3<2 and build and deploy the code, then it will resolve the issue. Even if requirements.txt doesnt have that please add it, because there might be some installations for which urllib3 will be a prerequisite and that will be downloaded even if its not mentioned directly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I tried for the above error is creating virtual environment in python using

```
python -m venv <name_of_virtualenv>
```

and then installing boto3 in the virtual environment.

Comment: ...and did it work? Please read [answer].