# ImportError: cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

How can I solve this error, I'm trying to load dataset locally on jupyter notebook.

```
path=os.path.join("C:\\Users\\Adeel\\fashion-product-images-small")

from datasets import load_dataset
print(path)
fashion = load_dataset(
   path,
    split="train"
)
fashion
```

I try to load dataset but on Jupyter notebook, it gives the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS' from
> 'urllib3.util.ssl_'

Answer (score 0):

There is very little context in your question. For example, I don't know which other dependencies you use. However, I encountered the same error before, and with me it was caused by a `botocore` dependency which caused a conflict with `urllib3>=2.0.0`. So, you may want to check your dependencies. Or even better, try `urllib3<2`.

See also: ["cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_'" on AWS Lambda using a layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76414514/cannot-import-name-default-ciphers-from-urllib3-util-ssl-on-aws-lambda-us)